# Creating new table like old table

Tags: mysql

When we create a copy of a table in this condition old table CONSTRAINT are not copied, I used

```
create table new_table like old_table;
```

so what i do that we can also copy the old_table CONSTRAINT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From the [CREATE TABLE docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)**

CREATE TABLE ... LIKE does not preserve any DATA DIRECTORY or INDEX DIRECTORY table options that were specified for the original table, or any foreign key definitions.

**From the [CREATE TABLE... SELECT docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html)**

CREATE TABLE ... SELECT does not automatically create any indexes for you. This is done intentionally to make the statement as flexible as possible. If you want to have indexes in the created table, you should specify these before the SELECT statement.

**Conclusion**

So in other words it is not directly possible..

**Work around**

In my projects I almost always use `SHOW CREATE TABLE old_table` to get the SQL and manually tweak the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
```

Then you insert with

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Comment: You appear to have told the OP to do exactly what he said doesn't work. `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` does not copy the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

It's already specified in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html).

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

Comment: You not only lose the constraints with that, you lose the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this both queries

```
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table;
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Comment: You appear to have told the OP to do exactly what he said doesn't work. `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` does not copy the constraints.